# Unable to resolve module "ActivityIndicator" from when installing react-native-video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

[image: ScreenShot]

I receive this error once I installed the react-native-video npm package. As soon as I uninstall the react-native-video package my app seems to work fine. I know that this component is referring to a React Native base component "ActivityIndicator" just not sure how the react-native-video package is related and causing this error.

Comment: Did you go through the installation steps described [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video)?

Comment: I did yeah and now I am receiving this error https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/438 and have updated Libraries through xcode. Still not working.